# Dynamically Resizing Table to last row?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a table that I would like to resize dynamically in VBA.
My current code is this:

```
Sub resizedata()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ob As ListObject
Dim Lrow1 As Long

Lrow1 = Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")
Set ob = ws.ListObjects("Table28")

ob.Resize ob.Range.Resize(Lrow1)

End Sub
```

I would like to add one condition onto this though...

1. The table should resize to before the first 0 in column J.

For instance:

```
+-------+--------+-------+
|Date(I)|Hours(J)| Sal(K)|
+-------+--------+-------+
| Aug   | 150000 | 12356 |
| Sep   |  82547 |  8755 |
| Oct   |  92857 | 98765 |
| Nov   |  10057 | 45321 |
| Dec   |      0 |     0 |
| Jan   |      0 |     0 |
+-------+--------+-------+
```

The above table's last row should be the November row because December is the first 0 value in column J.

Can anyone assist in revising my existing code?

Comment: You're checking `lRow1` to be the last row...so VBA is "correctly" resizing to your `0` row. You instead need to loop through those rows until a row doesn't equal zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
With Sheets("Sheet4")

    Lrow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    Do While .Cells(Lrow1, "J").Value=0
        Lrow1 = Lrow1 - 1
    Loop

End With
```

Answer (score 3):

This should help you to automatically resize the table.

```
   With Worksheets("sheet-name").ListObjects("table-name")
        .Resize .Range(1, 1).CurrentRegion
    End With
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there a particular reason you want to do this in VBA? You can simply create a defined name and use the following to create a self-adjusting range:

```
OFFSET(Sheet!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet!$A:$A),COUNTA(Sheet!$1:$1))
OFFSET(reference, rows, cols, [height], [width])
```

The top line shows typical usage, 2nd line is the official syntax.

Go into Name Manager on the Formulas tab, click new, give it a name and paste the code into Refers to:.

One caveat, it looks as though your data has 0's where there are no values. If that is truly the case, you'll have to do a different test to determine height.

One benefit of this method is that it is always calculated. If the data changes then the size definition of your named range adjusts as needed.

I hope this is helpful, I use this a lot...

Comment: Normally I would just use a pivot table for this, but for this particular data set I need to use a calculated field that I'm not sure can be done in a pivot table (at least so far as I can tell). Basically I'm taking the table and then exporting it into a chart for visualization. The dynamically resizing effect is because of the chart looks quite ugly if the a slicer item is selected where there are null values present. Thank you for your information. I'll definitely use this in the future.

Comment: Have you used calculated fields in Pivot Tables? They are somewhat limited, but can be very useful. To add a calculated field select a pivot table, then click Options on the PivotTable Tools tab, to the right in the Calculations area is Fields, Items, & Sets. Click Calculated Field and let the fun begin! (intuitive af, no?)

Comment: Yes, I've used calculated fields quite extensively. I believe I've ran into one of the "limitations" of calculated fields this time around though, that's why I was just wanting to stick with a standard table in this instance.